# CHtml:Link in CListView

Tags: php, yii, clistview

I am new to Yii. In one of my page I am using the below code to list company names as link.

```
<?php 
  $ads = Ads::model()->findAll();
  foreach ($ads as $ad)
  {
  ?>
    <li>
  <?php
    echo CHtml::link($ad->company,array('/user/ads/view/id/'.$ad->id.'/')).'<br>';                                                                                                                                          ?>
    </li>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

I want to change it to CListView. 
 please somebody help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CListView expects an ActiveDataProvider, so you should change your code to something like this:

```
<?php 
    $ads = new Ads; // and then use the search() method to return an activedataprovider
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $ads->search(),
        'itemView' => '_myview',
        'id' => 'blogslistview',       
)); 
?>
```

This wil render the `_myview.php` for each record. In the `_myview.php` file you can access the records attributes with `$data->myattribute`

So your `_myview.php` could look something like this:

```
<li>
<?php
echo CHtml::link($data->company, array('/user/ads/view/id/' . $data->id . '/'));
?>
</li>
```

More info:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$ads,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'id'=>'blogslistview',       
)); 
?>
```

Ref: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/229/filter-search-with-clistview/